# How to make changes in outer scope when overriding onDataChange function

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get data from firebase, iterate it and add items to array. but i cant do it from onDataCreate function because its not working

```
package com.example.cities

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.ListView
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_show.*

class ShowActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var db: DatabaseReference
    lateinit var listView: ListView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show)


        val cities = arrayListOf<String>("Test1")
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Cities")

        db.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("not implemented")
            }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                    for (i in p0.children) {
                        val city: String = i.value.toString()
                        cities.add(city)
                        println(city)
                    }
            }
        })
        cities.add("Test2")
        listView = findViewById(R.id.listview)
        listView.adapter =
            ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, cities)
    }
}
```

Test1 and Test2 are working fine but the main problem is that cities.add(city) doesnt work while println(city) does. as i see it cant make changes outside of scope so i need help to do that.

Comment: Could you use `mutableListOf<String>` instead? And what do you mean with "doesn't work"? Is not adding the data inside the list? Or what?

Comment: yes it doesnt do anything

Comment: mutableListOf doesnt work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addValueEventListener` is asynchronous and returns immediately.  `onDataChange` is called some time later with the results of the query, whenever it becomes available. Your code is incorrectly assuming the the results are immediately available.  What you should do instead is populate views in the callback, after the data is known the be available.

```
    db.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            // DATA FIRST BECOMES AVAILABLE HERE
            for (i in p0.children) {
                val city: String = i.value.toString()
                println(city)
                cities.add(city)
            }
            // ONLY POPULATE THE LISTVIEW WHEN THE DATA IS READY
            listView = findViewById(R.id.listview)
            listView.adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this@ShowActivity, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, cities)
        }
    })
```

Comment: "none of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied " ArrayAdapter says

Comment: See the edit. You need to specify which `this` is to be passed to ArrayAdapter